# 1 Dimensional Representation of Fusion Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, systems-of-equations, representation-of-algebras

Context: I am a physics grad student studying the fusion ring of topological defect lines in 2d CFTs.

Consider a commutative ring with elements $\mathcal{L_1}, \mathcal{L_2}, ... \mathcal{L_n}$ such that the product of any two element obeys the following fusion rule $$\mathcal{L_i}.\mathcal{L_j} = \sum_k N_{i\;\;j}^{\;k} \;\mathcal{L_k}$$ where $N_{i\;\;j}^{\;k}$ are called the fusion coefficients. For some (irrelevant) physical reason, $N_{i\;\;j}^{\;k} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Also, $N_{i\;\;j}^{\;k}$ are constrained such that the product is associative.

Finding one-dimensional representations would amount to solving $n(n+1)/2$ quadratic equations given by the fusion rule where $\mathcal{L_i}$'s would be treated as complex or real numbers.

Question: Does there always exist a 1-dimensional representation over $\mathbb{C}$ of such fusion rings? Does there always exist a 1-dimensional representation over $\mathbb{R}$ of such fusion rings? Is this system of equations overdetermined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In more mathematical language, the question is: suppose $R$ is a commutative ring whose underlying abelian group is a free abelian group of finite rank, such that there exists a basis of $R$ whose [structure constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants) are non-negative. Must $R$ admit a homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$ or to $\mathbb{R}$?

The answer is yes for $\mathbb{C}$ and I'm not sure what it is for $\mathbb{R}$. For $\mathbb{C}$ the argument is straightforward. We work with the extension of scalars $A = R \otimes \mathbb{C}$, which is a finite-dimensional commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Then the quotient $A/J(A)$ by the [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) is semisimple, hence (by the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem)) a finite direct product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$. So $A$ admits at least one homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$ and hence so does $R$. This argument makes no use of the constraint on the structure constants.

For $\mathbb{R}$ the answer to the question is "no" if we drop the constraint on the structure constants since $R$ could be $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. With the constraint the answer is "yes" with a mild additional hypothesis ("transitivity"); in the transitive case there exists a homomorphism to $\mathbb{R}$ given by the [Frobenius-Perron dimension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius-Perron+dimension). See Proposition 3.3.6 in Etingof et al.'s *[Tensor Categories](https://math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf)*. I don't know what happens if transitivity is dropped.

Comment: Over C, you can just pick a maximal ideal and quotient by that.

Comment: Of course, thanks!